# Connect mirrored object with a face

Tags: faces

I'm trying to connect faces witch are mirrored and extruded to the middle. And when I try to fill it does not work

[image: Example]

[image: When I use fill]

Comment: maybe you could delete the mirrored mesh and all these edges, then extrude the mesh, instead of trying to fill?

Comment: Thanks @moonboots that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the mirrored mesh and all these edges, then extrude the mesh, instead of trying to fill.